# plot individual and population regression lines with lmer

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I'm working with the `cake` dataset and constructed the following model

```
mod <- lmer(angle ~ recipe*temp + (1|replicate), data=cake)
newdat <- expand.grid(recipe=unique(cake$recipe),
              temp=c(min(cake$temp),
                     max(cake$temp)))
```

Then I wanted to plot the regression lines for each `replicate` separately for each `recipe` (`A`, `B` and `C`)

```
 ggplot(cake, aes(x=temp, y=angle, color=recipe)) +
      geom_line(aes(y=predict(mod), group=replicate, size="Replicate")) +
      geom_line(data=newdat, aes(y=predict(mod, re.form=~0, newdata=newdat), size="Population")) +
      scale_size_manual(name="Predictions", values=c("Replicate"=0.5, "Population"=1))
```

I have two questions. First, it seems that `Population` lines `B` and `C` are not parallel, even though I haven't defined a random slope model.
Second, I cannot make the code above to plot the regression lines for each `replicate` split by `recipe`.

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular provide complete minimal reproducible code including all inputs and library statements so others can  easily run the code by copying and pasting into their session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, your lines are not parallel because you have an interaction term between `recipe` and `temp` in your formula. You therefore have different slopes for the *fixed effects* (i.e. the change in `angle` per unit change in `temp` is dependent on `recipe`). We can see this even if we plot a simple `lm`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

mod <- lm(angle ~ recipe * temp, data = cake)

newdat <- expand.grid(recipe=unique(cake$recipe),
                      temp=c(min(cake$temp),
                             max(cake$temp)))
newdat$angle <- predict(mod, newdata = newdat)

ggplot(cake, aes(temp, angle, color = recipe)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 1)) +
  geom_line(data = newdat) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25, 40))
```

[image]

To answer the second question, you need to group by the interaction of `replicate` and `recipe` to get correctly colored lines for each of the replicates. You also need to have individual `lm` generated lines for them. The easiest way to do this is via `geom_smooth` with `method = lm`:

```r
ggplot(cake, aes(temp, angle, color = recipe)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 1)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = interaction(replicate, recipe)), se = FALSE, method = lm)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron, it's very clear now. However, the idea was to visualize mixed-model data but in both of your plots you plotted a lm. I understand that my original code is probably doing the same, so the question is whether this is a good representation of the mixed effects data? For example, isn't it a problem that `recipe` is a repeated-measures factor and `lm(angle ~ recipe*temp)` ignores that?

Comment: @locus. Yes, I'm not suggesting you use these exact plots, I was just using them to answer the specific questions you had. With an `lmer` the first plot would look very similar, but the slopes and intercepts will be slightly different from the `lm` version. To demonstrate a random intercept lmer, a typical strategy would be to plot lines for each replicate, and within replicates to have the slope fixed and only the intercept changed. It really depends what / who you are making the visualisation for.